# How to disable auto insertion of comment header when pressing enter, but keep auto insertion of header when auto wrapping comment?

Tags: key-bindings, formatting, comments

When editing `c` and `cpp` files, this is the behavior I want to achieve:

- When typing a comment line of the form `// Line...`, pressing `<CR>` **should not** add the comment header `//` in the next line.
- However, if while typing the `// Line...`, the line length exceeds the `tw` I  set, auto wrap should break the line, and **should** insert `//` in the next line.
- The auto comment insertion behavior of `/* * * */` style comments **should not change**. That is, after typing in `/*`, both explicitly hitting `<CR>` and auto wrap should insert `*` into the next line, produce the single space indentation, and if I type `/`, it should close the comment block with `*/`, properly indented.

I have `fo=tcrqn` and `comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://` set for `c` and `cpp` files.

I tried the following:

- Following the suggestion in [this](https://superuser.com/a/963068/1180806) superuser answer, modified for `inoremap` instead of `nnoremap`:

```
inoremap <silent> <cr> <esc>:set paste<cr>o<esc>:set nopaste<cr>:startinsert<cr>`
```

This does not work because although the desired behavior for `//` style single line comments are achieved, it destroys the behavior of `/* * * */` style block comments, preventing auto insertion of `*` characters when I press `<cr>` in a comment block.

- Then I tried modifying it to the following:

```
inoremap <silent> <cr> <esc>:set comments-=://<cr>:set comments+=f://<cr>o<esc>:set comments-=f://<cr> set comments+=://<cr>:startindent!<cr>
```

This mostly works, except that when the `*` is inserted by pressing `<cr>` in the block `/* * * */` comments, the inserted indentation is now missing. That is, representing the cursor position with `|`, after pressing `<cr>` I want something like:

```
/*
 * Line ... here I press <cr>
 * | <- Notice space between cursor and *
 */
```

But what I get is:

```
/*
 * Line ... here I press <cr>
 *| <- No space between cursor and *
 */
```

- I tried to fix the missing indentation problem by adding and deleting a space character:

```
inoremap <silent> <cr> <esc>:set comments-=://<cr>:set comments+=f://<cr>o<Space><BS><esc>:set comments-=f://<cr> set comments+=://<cr>:startindent!<cr>
```

This does fix the indentation issue, but now I have a new problem: typing `/` does not close the comment bock, but instead inserts an `/` character. This is what I want:

```
/*
 * ...
 * | <- cursor is here. I type '/', and the line becomes:
 */  <- Notice no space between * and /
```

But I get:

```
/*
 * ...
 * | <- cursor is here. I type '/', and the line becomes:
 * / <- Notice there is a space between * and /, comment block is not closed.
```

At this point I am out of ideas. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: So basically you want `fo=tcrqn` for `/**/`, and `fo=tcqn` for `//`, right?

Comment: The easiest solution is to use `o` instead of `<CR>` when you don't want a comment to continue.

Comment: @Matt, yes, basically `fo=tcrqn` for `/**/` and `fo=tcqn` for `//` is what I want. I want to avoid having to use a different key for ending and continuing comments, if possible.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, it's easier to do simply:

```
inoremap <expr><CR> getline('.') =~# '^\s*//' ? '<C-O>o' : '<CR>'
```

Perhaps, this mapping (with `<buffer>` modifier, of course) should be added to `after/ftplugin/c.vim` and not to the global `.vimrc`

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked very well. I have incorporated this into an `ftplugin` file according to the suggestions made by @fibranden.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of removing `://` from `'comments'` can be made to work, but instead of leaving Insert mode with `<Esc>`, use [`<C-\><C-O>`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-%5C_CTRL-O) to run a single Normal command (in this case, the `:` command to run the Ex `:set` command), returning to Insert mode as soon as that command is completed.

Using `<C-\><C-O>` here instead of `<C-O>` is important to preserve the cursor position and not lose the whitespace after the `*` as you were experiencing. The `<C-\><C-O>` command works "like `<C-O>` but don't move the cursor." (is what its help says.)

This mapping works:

```
inoremap <silent> <CR> <C-\><C-o>:set comments-=://<CR><CR><C-\><C-o>:set comments+=://<CR>
```

Additionally, you might want to keep this mapping only for file type `cpp` and maybe also `c`, so I'd recommend adding an additional `<buffer>` flag to the `inoremap` command, and storing it in a file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp_comments.vim` so it's loaded for the `cpp` filetype.

If you also want it for `c` (or other filetypes with the same comment style), you can have file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c_comments.vim` load it through a command such as:

```
source <sfile>:h/cpp_comments.vim
```

To load the file by that name from the same directory.

For completeness, you might also want to update the [`b:undo_ftplugin`](https://vimhelp.org/usr_41.txt.html#undo_ftplugin) variable, to undo the mapping if you change `'filetype'` of the current buffer. In order to do that, add the following snippet to the `cpp_comments.vim` file with the mapping:

```
if !exists("b:undo_ftplugin")
  let b:undo_ftplugin = ""
endif
let b:undo_ftplugin = b:undo_ftplugin . "|sil! exe 'iunmap <buffer> <CR>'"
```

---

**NOTE:** This answer doesn't fix the issue of closing the `/* ... */` comment block with a single `/`, so @Matt's mapping is much better than this one in that sense.

Still refer to this answer for the `ftplugin` part (which @Matt also mentions) and the `undo_ftplugin` part.